# Analysis Of Variance

Tags: anova, mathematical-statistics

How does the assumption of normality of errors in the analysis of variance help in interval estimation of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Normality makes it possible to derive the sampling distribution under the null hypothesis. It also justifies the use of Wald-type CIs, similar in way that a t-test and Wald CI are justified in regression.